# get_the_terms issue

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to list the custom taxonomy term that is attached to the post in question (which is a custom post type). I want to list it without it being a link, it is in fact a title.

I've tried this, but it clearly doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

```
function woocommerce_output_product_brand() {

$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'brand' );
foreach($terms as $term){
    echo $term; }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, what is `$post`? If you after the global `$post`, then you have to declare the global in the function. So on the second line you'll need to put `global $post;`.

Secondly, `$term` is an object. If you are after the term's name, use `$term->name`, for it's slug `$term->slug`.

[See the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) for some examples of how to use `get_the_terms`